# View in weight paint mode is too dark

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

I just switched from Blender 2.79b to 2.80 and I was playing around with 2.8, but when I got to weight painting, the object is so dark that I can't see the vertices of the object. I've set my monitor to the highest brightness as well, and it doesn't fix the issue. Also, is there a way to lock my screen to orthographic? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Go to the viewport shading and check *X-Ray*.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using "Look Dev" Shading while using a dark Material/bad lighting. Press <kbd>Z</kbd> and switch to "Solid"

[image: Weight Paint]

Answer (score 0):

I went into my preferences, went to light, and installed "studio lights," and set all the settings to the brightest settings. It seemed to help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Zagstrug's solution is probably what you want, as weighted paints are tuned to have good contrast against the default viewport background.  Also realize that you can change the color of the viewport background:
[image]